# Access SQL count number of people group by week number

Tags: sql, ms-access

I need to count how many people are working given a week number.

Here's my people table (date is US format) :

```
name | surname| date_of_entry | date_of_exit
-----|--------|---------------|-------------
foo  | bar    | 1/1/2006      | 1/8/2006
foo1 | bar1   | 1/5/2010      |
foo2 | bar2   | 2/3/2015      | 3/4/2015
```

and I'd like for a given year to have all weeks number with the proper number of people working during this period.
I hope you understand me because english is not my native language sorry.

I've done some research and from what i understand i need to create a table with all weeks starting from 1/1/2006 and ending "now" (because people with no exit date are still working) according to the example above to be able to test for each person if he was working during this week so I can count him in my query.

I'm still a student programmer but it seems to be a pretty complex SQL query to me.

**Expected output for a query for year 2006 (with the new year starting a monday) :**

```
week_number | count
------------|------
   1        | 1
   2        | 1
   3        | 0
   etc..    | 0
```

until 1/5/2010 where all weeks have 1 in the field "count"
and then **query for year 2015 :**

```
week_number | count
------------|------
   1        | 1
   2        | 1
   ...      | 1
   9        | 2
   ...      | 2
   14       | 1
   ...      | 1
```

If anybody can help me to resolve this it would be awesome, thanks!

Comment: You will need the _year_ as well because standard ISO weeks cross calendar year boundaries. Or, if you have a custom week number, expand the week table to hold the start date of the week and/or the end date. Also, you must define if "working during a week" means working the full week or just a part of it.

Comment: For the moment, my weeks table has four fields : **year, week_number, week_start, week_end** and i'm currently trying to populate it with VBA code. "Working during a week" is ambiguous for me too, but let's say that if someone is working more than 3 days then he is working the full week (if this is not too complicated).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are lucky I have to change my mind for 15 minutes.

---

### Step 1 : Create Calendar table

Create a new table named `Calendar` with the following fields

- `id` : autonumber
- `Cal_Year` : number
- `Cal_Week` : number

In a module, add the following code and execute it (F5) :

```
Private Sub Create_Calendar_table()

    Dim Y As Integer
    Dim W As Integer

    For Y = 2006 To 2016
        For W = 1 To 52
            DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO Calendar (cal_year, cal_week) VALUES (" & Y & "," & W & ")"
        Next W
    Next Y

End Sub
```

`Calendar` table is now ready to use :

```
ID  Cal_year    Cal_week
1   2006        1
2   2006        2
3   2006        3
4   2006        4
5   2006        5
    and so on...
```

---

### Step 2 : Create the query

*Note that I am in Europe so my dates are DD/MM. This won't affect your results.*

I decompose so you understand the process.

First we need to create a date from the year/week in the calendar table, this can be achieved like this

```
SELECT Cal_year, Cal_week, DateAdd("ww",Cal_week,DateSerial(Cal_year,1,1)) AS thedate
FROM Calendar

Cal_year    Cal_week    thedate
2006            1       8/01/2006
2006            2       15/01/2006
2006            3       22/01/2006
2006            4       29/01/2006
2006            5       5/02/2006   
and so on...
```

Next, since we will work on ranges of dates, it is important a to attribute the *current date* when the people's exit_date is `NULL`, like this :

```
nz(date_of_exit, Now)
```

The field is prepared.

Then, the trick.

We need to `JOIN` our calendar table with the people table in manner that will return a record for every week on which a person is present.

The key to achieve this is the `ON...BETWEEN...AND`

```
SELECT C.Cal_year, C.Cal_Week, P.pname, P.psurname, P.date_of_entry, nz(P.date_of_exit, Now) AS exit_date
FROM [Calendar] C
INNER JOIN ( SELECT [Name] AS pname, [surname] as psurname, date_of_entry, date_of_exit
            FROM people
           ) P  
ON (DateAdd("ww",C.Cal_week,DateSerial(C.Cal_year,1,1)) BETWEEN P.date_of_entry  AND nz(P.date_of_exit, Now))
ORDER BY  C.Cal_year, C.Cal_Week             

Cal_year    Cal_Week pname      psurname    date_of_entry       exit_date
2006            1   foo         bar         1/01/2006               8/01/2006
2010            1   foo1        bar1        5/01/2010               22/04/2016 13:04:39
2010            2   foo1        bar1        5/01/2010               22/04/2016 13:04:39
2010            3   foo1        bar1        5/01/2010               22/04/2016 13:04:39
2010            4   foo1        bar1        5/01/2010               22/04/2016 13:04:39
```

Note that if you need ALL WEEKS since 2006, even those for which nobody is present, just change the `INNER JOIN` with a `LEFT JOIN`

And finally, we exploit the previous query to count the presences by doing a  `GROUP BY` on year and week of the calendar table, and we specify the year 2015 in the `WHERE` clause otherwise it will count everything since 2006. Which implies that it is very easy to count the presences for any year.

```
SELECT yyyy, ww , count(*) AS cnt
FROM
(         
    SELECT C.Cal_year AS yyyy, C.Cal_Week AS ww
    FROM [Calendar] C
    INNER JOIN ( SELECT [Name] AS pname, [surname] as psurname, 
                       date_of_entry,  
                       date_of_exit
                FROM people
               ) P  ON (DateAdd("ww",C.Cal_week,DateSerial(C.Cal_year,1,1)) BETWEEN P.date_of_entry  AND nz(P.date_of_exit, Now))
)
WHERE yyyy=2015
GROUP BY yyyy, ww
ORDER BY yyyy, ww

yyyy    ww  cnt
2015    1   1
2015    2   1
2015    3   1
2015    4   1
2015    5   1
2015    6   1
2015    7   1
2015    8   1
2015    9   2
2015    10  2
2015    11  2
2015    12  2
2015    13  2
2015    14  1
2015    15  1
2015    16  1
```

---

Well, it took me 40 minutes finally...

Comment: thanks mate it works perfectly, i just replaced the between by <= and >= operators because access was giving me an error "between operator without AND in query expression" but now everything's good!

Comment: @zogota strange... I tested everything on Access 2010

Comment: i'm working on access 2013 and it happens when i enter query builder and then quit or when i try "GUI" sorting when in table view, I think it's a bug where ms access add parentheses to the query where it should not and then everything fail but it's not a problem anymore. I have still a hard time understanding how the join works because of the "dateadd" function and the BETWEEN operator, i've never done such thing before. My other question is what's the purpose of **id** in calendar table ? I use **cal_week and cal_year** as PK, I tried with auto-id but it didn't seem faster.

Comment: @zogota the id  of the cal table doesn't have a specific purpose here, I just have a habbit of always making a technical PK in my tables. you can remove this columnt if you want. Regarding the bug... I am figthing MS access bugs everyday so it's a possible explanation. What you can do is create a Query with the `INNER JOIN BETWEEN AND` query. And then the last query will become `SELECT yyyy, ww , count(*) AS cnt FROM thequery WHERE yyyy=2015 GROUP BY yyyy, ww`. This might solve some issues as  well as giving more flexibility (if you want to query another year or a specific week for instance)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a query to find the weeks working:

```
Select 
    [name],
    surname,
    year,
    week
From
    PeopleTable,
    WeekTable
Where
    (date_of_entry <= week_start And DateDiff("d", week_start, date_of_exit) >= 3)
        Or
    (date_of_entry >= week_start And date_of_exit <= week_end
    And
    DateDiff("d", date_of_entry, date_of_exit >= 3)
        Or
    (DateDiff("d", date_of_entry, week_end) >= 3 And date_of_exit >= week_end)        
Group By
    [name],
    surname,
    year,
    week
```

Now, save this and create a new query where you use WeekTable as source (to list all weeks) with an outer join to the query above (to list the worked weeks). In this, Group By the year and week and add a count to get the count of working employees for each week.

Comment: thanks for you help, i still used Thomas' solution because you don't need to store **week_start** and **week_end**.