# How to group by month including all months?

Tags: oracle, group-by, calendar, date-arithmetic

I group my table by months

```
  SELECT TO_CHAR (created, 'YYYY-MM') AS operation, COUNT (id)
    FROM user_info
   WHERE created IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY ROLLUP (TO_CHAR (created, 'YYYY-MM'))

2015-04 1
2015-06 10
2015-08 22
2015-09 8
2015-10 13
2015-12 5
2016-01 25
2016-02 37
2016-03 24
2016-04 1
2016-05 1
2016-06 2
2016-08 2
2016-09 7
2016-10 103
2016-11 5
2016-12 2
2017-04 14
2017-05 2
        284
```

But the records don't cover all the months.
I would like the output to include all the months, with the missing ones displayed in the output  with a default value:

```
2017-01 ...
2017-02 ...
2017-03 ZERO
2017-04 ZERO
2017-05 ...
```

Comment: Search for *calendar table*, there are plenty of questions like this on SO. You can find inspiration on [this complete solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36789953/access-sql-count-number-of-people-group-by-week-number/36792224#36792224) I posted last year, it's for Access but the principle is the same for all RDBMS

Comment: Please show a [mcve] with valid sql, including WHERE clause, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle has [a good array of date manipulation functions](https://docs.oracle.com/database/122/SQLRF/Single-Row-Functions.htm#GUID-5652DBC2-41C7-4F07-BEDD-DAF620E35F3C). The two pertinent ones for this problem are

- `MONTHS_BETWEEN()` which calculates the number of months between two dates
- `ADD_MONTHS()` which increments a date by the given number of months

We can combine these functions to generate a table of all the months spanned by your table's records. Then we use an outer join to conditionally join records from USER_INFO to that calendar. When no records match `count(id)` will be zero.

```
with cte as (
  select max(trunc(created, 'MM')) as max_dt
         , min(trunc(created, 'MM')) as min_dt
  from user_info
  )
 , cal as (
    select add_months(min_dt, (level-1)) as mth
    from cte
    connect by level <= months_between(max_dt, min_dt) + 1
)
select to_char(cal.mth, 'YYYY-MM') as operation
       , count(id)
from  cal
     left outer join user_info
   on trunc(user_info.created, 'mm') = cal.mth
group by rollup (cal.mth)
order by 1
/
```