# Getting "filler" empty values for a GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql

Assuming I want to get 'weekly' results from a date range, and the date range contains four separate weeks, but my database only has a record for one week, how can I get filler values for the remaining three weeks?

For example, given this date range: 6/2018 - 7/2018

I run this query:

```
SELECT
 DATE_FORMAT(period, '%m %d') || ' - ' || DATE_FORMAT(period, '%m %d') AS period,
 SUM(clicks) AS clicks
FROM tablename
WHERE period >= ? AND period <= ?
GROUP BY YEAR(period), WEEK(period)
```

With these table rows in the database:

```
|         period          | clicks |
|  07/01/2018T:00:00:00Z  |  1000  |
```

And I get these query results:

```
|     period      | clicks |
|  Jul 1 - Jul 5  |  1000  |
```

But I want to get these query results to cover default values for the empty weeks so I can use them to populate a d3 chart:

```
|     period      | clicks |
|  Jul 1 - Jul 5  |  1000  | 
| Jun 25 - Jun 23 |  0     |
| Jun 18 - Jun 24 |  0     |
| Jun 12 - Jun 18 |  0     |
```

Any ideas? This sort of "filler" phenomena should be generic enough to work with other intervals, such as daily, monthly, yearly, hourly.

Comment: In most RDBMS we achieve such results using a **Calendar table**. You should create your own calendar table and JOIN it. Search for that, you will find plenty of examples here or on google. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36789953/access-sql-count-number-of-people-group-by-week-number/36792224?r=SearchResults&s=1|49.4913#36792224](This answer) from me is a good example.

Comment: JOIN the table with `SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 ... SELECT 5`.

Answer (score 0):

rewrite your query as

```
ifnull( SUM(clicks),0) AS clicks
```

Comment: do you really think this is answering the question in any way?

Comment: ya.if value is null.it returns 0.he wants to show 0 anyway if the value is 0 in myself that return date also @ThomasG

Comment: @Ram Problem is, that in this case - without any data row for the given week - there will not be a result row to Group on, so "No row at all".

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query to generate the weeks and then left join with your current query to get what you want.

```
DECLARE @StartingFromDate DATETIME = '2018-12-01';
DECLARE @EndingAtDate DATETIME = '2018-12-31';

WITH CTE_DateRange (DateRange)
    AS (SELECT DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0, @EndingAtDate) - DATEDIFF(WEEK, @StartingFromDate, @EndingAtDate), 0)
        UNION ALL
        SELECT DATEADD(WEEK, 1, DateRange)
        FROM CTE_DateRange
        WHERE DATEADD(WEEK, 1, DateRange) < @EndingAtDate)
SELECT CTE_DateRange.DateRange
FROM CTE_DateRange
WHERE CTE_DateRange.DateRange BETWEEN @StartingFromDate AND @EndingAtDate
```